# A particle slides on the inner surface of a paraboloid. Is the constraint rheonomic or scleronomic?

Tags: classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

To my understanding, a constraint is said to be rheonomic if the constraint equation explicitly depends on time. For a particle moving on the surface of a paraboloid, the condition that needs to be met is that the coordinates on the particle must satisfy the equation of the paraboloid. So I believe the constraint must be scleronomic, as there is no explicit time dependence here. But the given answer to this question is that the constraint is rheonomic. How is it so?

Comment: I would tend to agree with you. Can you give (or display) the source for the question?

Comment: Sorry, it was given to us in an assignment. I don't know if it was taken from a standard reference book.